# Gitlab Pipeline Job Token Fail

Tags: azure, docker, ubuntu, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

I have Gitlab Community and I am trying to integrate it with SonarQube. The Sonar is hosted on Azure VM Ubuntu in a Docker container. The problem is that I really don't know how to write `gitlab-ci.yml`. I already try sonar, but locally hosted on a Windows machine. Here is my current `gitlab-ci.yml`.

When I change sonar host with my current and I am not sure what I need to put on sonar. Login then throws an error:

> SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.0.4
> Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
> Pre-processing started.
> Preparing working directories...
> 18:35:07.168  Updating build integration targets...
> 18:35:07.394  The token you provided doesn't have sufficient rights to check license.

```yaml
sonar-check:
  image:
    name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    - choco install sonarqube-scanner.portable
    - SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"somefile" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" /d:sonar.login="8f6658e7684de225a4f45c7cf3466d462a95c1c7"   
    - nuget restore -ConfigFile .\nuget.config
    - MsBuild.exe ./Process /t:Rebuild
    - SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="8f6658e7684de225a4f45c7cf3466d462a95c1c7"
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
    - develop
    - GitLabQualityTool
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone coming here for a similar problem where you had things set up correctly and suddenly they stopped working, I just experienced this. I had to generate a new auth token and that got things working correctly. I don't have an explanation for why that occurred though, but this is a troubleshooting step one could take.

Comment: Thanks for talking the time to post this!

Answer (score 7):

Maybe your SonarQube scanner is out of date

I faced the Same Issue [image: Error Message]

I solved this issue by this command
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-sonarscanner

[image]

And it worked right after

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. You need to go to your sonar MyAccount->Security->Generate Token.
This token must be added here:

```
- SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"somefile" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" /d:sonar.login="8f6658e7684de225a4f45c7cf3466d462a95c1c7" 
- SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login="8f6658e7684de225a4f45c7cf3466d462a95c1c7"
```

and your sonar URL.

Answer (score 1):

make sure when you do create Ci file for sonar scan then u need to check which image are you using because for ***sonar 10.x*** version we are using **sonar.token** parameters instead of **sonar.login** so either your token is correct you will get issue because if  use old image with ***sonar 10.x*** version you will get issue like token issue in my case i have update ***sonar 10.x*** and i was using my customize image which old used by ***sonar 9.x*** . make user this points to avoid such silly issue's